# In Typescript, how can I make a generic service that can call static methods on a model defined by a type param

Tags: typescript, dependency-injection, sequelize-typescript

I want to do something like this:

```
import {Company} from 'company.model.ts'

@Service()
export class CompanyService extends BaseService<Company> {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.Model = Company
  }
}

@Service()
export class BaseService<T extends typeof Model> {
  Model: typeof T
  async findAll(input) {
    return await this.Model.create(input)
  }
}
```

I want to call static methods on a class with a type of `typeof T`.

Also, is there a way to avoid having to assign a `typeof T` to an instance variable?

Answer (score 1):

Solution is to use:

```
Model: {new(): T} & typeof Sequelize.Model
```

Thanks to: https://github.com/RobinBuschmann/sequelize-typescript/issues/231#issuecomment-471724824